have been mistakenly marked as spam in your wallet
My name is Simon Atehortua, and I am the CEO of Throu, a real estate investment platform that uses blockchain technology to democratize access to real estate investments. Throu is committed to transparency and security, operating in compliance with regulations in LATAM.
We have recently observed that our tokens, specifically 0x9CC2485cA011833b3bAce1C2Cc78DCeEb8B19D1B, have been mistakenly marked as spam in your wallet. This is negatively affecting the experience of our users and the perception of our brand. We would appreciate your assistance in reviewing this classification and helping us ensure that our tokens are correctly displayed in the collectibles section of the Phantom wallet. We are available to provide any additional information necessary to resolve this situation.
Thank you for your attention to this matter. I look forward to your prompt response.

Most wallet (phantom and wallet) uses blowfish to monitor filter out irregular transactions and domains.
We had an issue with our domain too at Soundwork but resolved it by sending an email to their review team review@blowfish.xyz
